# Can we edit (position, scale, etc) glTF models on the server side (without three.js)?

Tags: node.js, three.js, gltf

I am trying to merge two gltf assets and I am using the sayduck gltf pipeline to achieve it. The problem is that I need one of the assets to be away from the other assets. eg. cat (0, 0, 0) and dog (10, 0, 0) so as to place them side by side for comparison

I have tried using three.js on the server side (node.js) and it is a bit hard to get the gltf parser to work on the server side. It would be great if it is achievable without using three.js.

Comment: You could also import both models into Blender, perform you changes and then export as a single `glTF` asset.

Comment: Hi @Mugen87, I am trying to do it on a server only using nodejs ( I fetch two 3d models from an API, merge, edit position and server it to the user) so I guess the Blender route does not work for me. Appreciate your response.

Comment: How did you use sayduck-pipeline as a javascript library to merge the files together?

Comment: @PatrickLüthi You can use the [sayduck gltf pipeline](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sayduck-gltf-pipeline) and run `sayduck-gltf-pipeline gltf-utility --gltf-merge merged_name.gltf -o path/to/output/folder/ path/to/first.gltf path/to/second.gltf`

Comment: @RamBa I will need to merge them in javascript code.. do you know any option for that?

Comment: @RamBa I dont know any method for that unfortunately. But it would be really helpful if you could pull it off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't need to use a 3D rendering library like threejs to edit a glTF file serverside. For the simplest case (repositioning an object in a `.gltf` file), you could just do:

```
const fs = require('fs');

// Read and parse file.
const gltfContent = fs.readFileSync('file.gltf', {encoding: 'utf8'});
const gltf = JSON.parse(gltfContent);

// Edit glTF asset.
const node = gltf.nodes.filter((n) => n.name === 'Cat')[0];
node.translation = [10, 0, 5];

// Write to disk.
fs.writeFileSync('file.gltf', JSON.stringify(gltf));
```

For more complex changes to a file, you'll want to either use an [existing parsing/writing tool](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF#gltf-tools) or learn about the [glTF specification](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/blob/master/specification/2.0/README.md).

Comment: Hi Don McCurdy, This is exactly what I was looking for. I did read through the specification but missed out translation as I expected position like in three.js. Greatly appreciate your contribution to AFRAME and threejs communities.